# Javascript code for google map is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I put a javascript function in my ruby on rails4 web page but it didn't work properly. My page not shows the map when I open my webpage but when I reload my webpage then map show properly. I put my javascript tag in body of my webpage. What should I do for proper working of code and where should I put my code that it can works properly?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.webestools.com/google_map_gen.js?lati=31.546678&long=74.330942&zoom=18&width=675&height=400&mapType=normal&map_btn_normal=yes&map_btn_satelite=yes&map_btn_mixte=yes&map_small=yes&marqueur=yes&info_bulle=" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [disabling Turbolinks](http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4).

If that works, [figure out how to make your code work with Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).  If it doesn't, best of luck!